# Why is a 500 error generated by admin-ajax.php not going into the Apache error log?

Tags: ajax, 500-internal-error

I'm getting 500 errors with AJAX on the admin side. However, these errors aren't being logged in the Apache logs so they're rather hard to debug.

Is there some way I can find out what they are?

Thanks

Comment: In WP, this maybe because you didn't install php5-curl library on your apache server.
Try enable it and restart server.
Thanks the help crue from [nelson](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-ajax-for-all-500-internal-server-error).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes I have a 500 error ( from NGinx ) just because I have a "character" getting outputted before the first header gets written ( or in-between ).

Activate WP_DEBUG = true and see what happens. 99% of the case I could spot the error from there. ( and it was nearly all the time the above error ).

Post back if that doesn't solve your debug difficulty problem. We'll have a look at your apache config by then.

Comment: To turn `WP_DEBUG` "on": https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/